# command line tool to process javascript inside markdown file

Tags: javascript, command-line, markdown

I have been searching quite extensively but I don't seem to find the answer (or probably not asking with the right words). Here is the thing:

I have a markdown file in which are some javascript parts. These are being very well processed through a browser. Now I want to process the very same file using pandoc to output context source and then build a pdf from it.

Since pandoc doesn't seem to interpret the javascript, at least to my knowledge, I'd like to have a command line (linux) tool that will interpret the javascript before using pandoc. To get a process abstracted as

```
cat mySource.md | ThatVerySpecialTool | pandoc > myContextInput.tex
```

The idea is to have the same source for both website and pdf. And since the website is already there and running, I'd really like to keep with the markdown source.

Although it seems very simple as a request I haven't been able to find anything out there to help me.

The scripts part looks like

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
document.write("something");
</script>
```

Many Thanks

Comment: Try this: [The same guy that asked the question posted an answer with a solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33250486/embed-markdown-md-into-html)