# Embed markdown (md) into HTML

Tags: javascript, html, embed, markdown

I need help embedding a markdown, or *.md, file inside of an HTML index file. I have found that I can embed HTML inside of markdown, but not vice-versa. This would help to increase the speed of my editing because markdown format is extremely easy to use, (as I'm using it now) and I don't have to change the format of  the rest of my site. I know that something like this is done to embed another HTML file with `<iframe src="path/to/html>html-name</iframe>`. I could also use javascript to interpret the md format on page load. Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: Have you tried [searching](http://strapdownjs.com/)?

Comment: Of course! Why would I post a question if I had already found an answer to it?

Comment: Just curious, because that link seems to do what you are asking unless you mean actually inject a markdown file into HTML

Comment: Actually that was what I meant, but that link works too! I can embed another HTML document with the markdown in it! Thanks

Comment: Wait... Nope. Just tried the code in my existing site... Not working. Just a white screen, I think the themes are conflicting. :/

Comment: Even if you leave out the theme? In that case, are you using any web-server frameworks like Node to serve your content? I have seen some [example node projects](https://scotch.io/tutorials/building-a-real-time-markdown-viewer) that either live-update markdown to html or just render a converted markdown file

Comment: Not supposed to say thaks in the comments, but thanks. Had to let you know it worked.

Comment: Welcome. I suppose you could answer your own question below, then, since I'm not sure what you changed/added to make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/zhlicen/md.htm An example of zeromd.js Just serve the md.htm file and md files, and visit directly by url:

```
/md.htm?src=README.md
```

Live demo: https://b.0-0.plus/blog/md.htm?src=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/vscode/main/README.md

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30403089)

Answer (score 18):

## Here's the solution that I have long since forgotten about:

[image: Tagdown Logo]

Forgetting that I asked this question and getting no answers, I created my own solution as an extension off of Chris Jeffrey's `marked.js`.

#### I call it `tagdown.js`.

**Here it is: http://spikespaz.com/tagdownjs/**

Just in case that link, or my domain, expires: https://spikespaz.github.io/tagdownjs/

Github: https://github.com/spikespaz/tagdownjs

This allows markdown to be added directly to the site, within a tag set with the class `markdown`. See the example on the site. There is no theme system in it, it's just the markdown parser.

## Update

The project, TagdownJS, has been deleted from Github. The code for it seems so simple that it doesn't deserve its own repository.

Until it finds a new home, just go find Christopher Jeffery's Marked.js, and use this following code with it.

```
document.body.style.display = "none"; // Hide the page until it's finished rendering.

document.createElement("markdown");
var md_tags = document.getElementsByTagName("markdown"); // Returns array of all markdown tags.

for (var i = 0; i < md_tags.length; i++) { // Iterate through all the tags, and generate the HTML.
    var md_text = md_tags[i].textContent.replace(/^[^\S\n]+/mg, ""); // I love regex, so shoot me.

    var md_div = document.createElement("div"); // Make a new div to replace the fake tag.
    md_div.id = "content";
    md_div.innerHTML = marked(md_text);

    md_tags[i].parentNode.appendChild(md_div); // Add remove the old raw markdown.
    md_tags[i].parentNode.removeChild(md_tags[i]);
}

document.body.style.display = ""; // Show the rendered page.
```

Answer (score 3):

Basicly, you need to interpret MD format into HTML. Javascript is an option.

Take below as an example. (Though Windows, independent of OS)

Let's say a folder *mytest* looks like,

```
D:\mytest>dir
 Volume in drive D is Data
 Volume Serial Number is ABCD-EFGH

 Directory of D:\mytest

12/03/2020  10:10 AM    <DIR>          .
12/03/2020  10:10 AM    <DIR>          ..
12/03/2020  10:09 AM             7,973 example-image.jpg
12/03/2020  10:12 AM             4,619 md_html.html
12/03/2020  10:00 AM             2,299 md_html.min.js
               3 File(s)         14,891 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  778,204,147,712 bytes free

D:\mytest>
```

Here is the *html* content,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.bootcss.com/highlight.js/9.12.0/styles/atom-one-light.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.bootcss.com/github-markdown-css/2.8.0/github-markdown.min.css" />
  <title>Marked In HTML</title>
</head>
<body>
  <template type="markdown">
    Try Marked In HTML ！
    ====
  </template>
</body>
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/marked/0.3.6/marked.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/highlight.js/9.12.0/highlight.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/highlight.js/9.12.0/languages/javascript.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="md_html.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  markedInHtml.init()
</script>
</html>
```

And the *js*,

```
!function(n){function t(r){if(e[r])return e[r].exports;var i=e[r]={i:r,l:!1,exports:{}};return n[r].call(i.exports,i,i.exports,t),i.l=!0,i.exports}var e={};t.m=n,t.c=e,t.i=function(n){return n},t.d=function(n,e,r){t.o(n,e)||Object.defineProperty(n,e,{configurable:!1,enumerable:!0,get:r})},t.n=function(n){var e=n&&n.__esModule?function(){return n.default}:function(){return n};return t.d(e,"a",e),e},t.o=function(n,t){return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(n,t)},t.p="",t(t.s=1)}([function(n,t,e){"use strict";function r(n){return n&&n.__esModule?n:{default:n}}function i(n){if(Array.isArray(n)){for(var t=0,e=Array(n.length);t<n.length;t++)e[t]=n[t];return e}return Array.from(n)}function a(n,t){if(!(n instanceof t))throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function")}Object.defineProperty(t,"__esModule",{value:!0}),t.MarkedInHtml=void 0;var o=function(){function n(n,t){for(var e=0;e<t.length;e++){var r=t[e];r.enumerable=r.enumerable||!1,r.configurable=!0,"value"in r&&(r.writable=!0),Object.defineProperty(n,r.key,r)}}return function(t,e,r){return e&&n(t.prototype,e),r&&n(t,r),t}}(),u=e(3),l=r(u),s=e(2),c=r(s);t.MarkedInHtml=function(){function n(){a(this,n),l.default.setOptions(this.options||{gfm:!0,tables:!0,breaks:!1,pedantic:!1,sanitize:!1,smartLists:!0,smartypants:!1,highlight:function(n,t,e){return c.default.highlightAuto(n).value}})}return o(n,[{key:"init",value:function(){var n=this;document.querySelectorAll('template[type="markdown"]').forEach(function(t){var e=document.createElement("div");e.innerHTML=n.parse(t),e.id=t.id,e.classList.add(["markdown-body"].concat(i(Array.from(t.classList)))),e.dataset.markdown=n.intelligentProcessingIndent(t),t.parentElement.replaceChild(e,t)})}},{key:"parse",value:function(n){return(0,l.default)(this.intelligentProcessingIndent(n))}},{key:"intelligentProcessingIndent",value:function(n){var t=n.innerHTML.split("\n");t.length&&/^\s*$/.test(t[0])&&t.shift(),t.length&&/^\s*$/.test(t[t.length-1])&&t.pop();var e=Math.min.apply(Math,i(t.map(function(n){return n.length?n.match(/^\s*/)[0].length:1/0})));return t.map(function(n){return n.substring(e)}).join("\n")}}]),n}()},function(n,t,e){"use strict";var r=e(0);window&&(window.markedInHtml=new r.MarkedInHtml)},function(n,t){n.exports=hljs},function(n,t){n.exports=marked}]);
```

And the *jpg*,
[image: example-image.jpg]

After open the *html*, you should be able to convert

```
Try Marked In HTML ！
    ====
```

into

[image: result.png]

You can try to replace the template, some effect may not be able to present. For example, use [quick markdown example by John Gabriele](http://www.unexpected-vortices.com/sw/rippledoc/quick-markdown-example.html), the **equation** are not shown well.

Someone, like  would suggest to use *snippet*, yet I failed to get that ❄️ work, parsing not successful.

Answer (score 3):

'md-block.js' seems to work for basic stuff:

```
<script type="module" src="https://md-block.verou.me/md-block.js"></script>
```

Then wrap your MD in an `md-block`

Here is in an easy example:

```
 <body>
        <h1>Normal HTML Heading</h1>
    
        <md-block>
            # Markdown Heading
            **Something in BOLD**
            ~~strikthrough~~
        </md-block>
    <script type="module" src="https://md-block.verou.me/md-block.js"></script>
</body>
```